# Setting, Removing or Overriding a SharedSizeGroup programmaticaly in WPF and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, edit, sharedsizegroup

So I have set a SharedSizeGroup though XAML to 2 columns on a grid in WPF, but I would like to know if there is a way to remove and re-set or override that property through code in C#?

I know already the code for applying this property to a column/row upon creation but I don't want to create or remove a new column/row. 
I just need to edit the property of an existing one.

Comment: What is the problem? [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) that SharedSizeGroup has both getter and setter, so it theoretically can be changed from code-behind. If it is not so, then provide [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I want to change dynamically through code, the sharedSizedGroup that a grid's column belongs to. So far what I ve seen is that you can set a columns sharedSizedGroup upon creation, but I can't find a way to change it after. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: What about `myGrid.Columns[0].SharedSizeGroup = "SomeGroup;"`? Or it  doesn't work? Create [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issues you encounter.